# Detecting duplicate lines on file using c

Tags: c, search, file-io, csv

I have a csv file with about (15000-25000) lines(of fixed size) and i want to know how can i detect duplicated lines using c language.

An example of the output is like this :

```
0123456789;CUST098WZAX;35
```

I have no memory or time constraint, so i want the simplest solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use an [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: If you have no memory or time constraint, then that means that the naive solutions are available to you... this means that unless you can't even meet the standard of "naive" that you should be able to think of them on your own. Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: @SanJacinto : well any simple solution is ok for me (no hash, no trees, etc..)

Comment: @iPadDeveloperJr Ok, so then what's the question? You know what it is you do not want to do, and you know what your desired end result. What have you thought of so far, and why won't this solution work for you?

Comment: Keep each line you read in an array. Check the latest line against all the lines already in the array. This is a O(n*n) solution though.

Comment: Sort the lines, then remove duplicates. In C++ you could use std::unique and std::sort.

Comment: @pmg : much better :), so i need reseize the array for each new line?

Comment: @AraK : Thanks, but i'm using C not C++.

Comment: No, you say you have 20000 lines fix, so there is no resizing needed

Comment: @Tim : about 20000 lines, not exactly 20000, i will edit the original post

Comment: If you want to resize the array (instead of using a fixed size), don't resize one-by-one. Double its size when you need to grow it to "minimize" the (heavy) reallocations. Also remember to have space for the terminating `'\0'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct somehash {
        struct somehash *next;
        unsigned hash;
        char *mem;
        };

#define THE_SIZE 100000
struct somehash *table[THE_SIZE] = { NULL,};

struct somehash **some_find(char *str, unsigned len);
static unsigned some_hash(char *str, unsigned len);

int main (void)
{
char buffer[100];
struct somehash **pp;
size_t len;

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
        len = strlen(buffer);
        pp = some_find(buffer, len);
        if (*pp) { /* found */
                fprintf(stderr, "Duplicate:%s\n", buffer);
                }
        else    {       /* not found: create one */
                fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);
                *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
                (*pp)->next = NULL;
                (*pp)->hash = some_hash(buffer,len);
                (*pp)->mem = malloc(1+len);
                memcpy((*pp)->mem , buffer,  1+len);
                }
        }
return 0;
}
struct somehash **some_find(char *str, unsigned len)
{
unsigned hash;
unsigned slot;
struct somehash **hnd;

hash = some_hash(str,len);
slot = hash % THE_SIZE;
for (hnd = &table[slot]; *hnd ; hnd = &(*hnd)->next ) {
        if ( (*hnd)->hash != hash) continue;
        if ( strcmp((*hnd)->mem , str) ) continue;
        break;
        }
return hnd;
}

static unsigned some_hash(char *str, unsigned len)
{
unsigned val;
unsigned idx;

if (!len) len = strlen(str);

val = 0;
for(idx=0; idx < len; idx++ )   {
        val ^= (val >> 2) ^ (val << 5) ^ (val << 13) ^ str[idx] ^ 0x80001801;
        }
return val;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the sheer pain you took to write out the entire program so elagantly :) It would be nice if you explain whats happening and also the complexity, so that future visitors can learn a lot

Comment: There is no complexity. The program is just a plain hash table storing lines of text. IMHO everyone with some C-reading ability should be able to understand it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: By complexity I mean some reference to things such as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) just for people like me who aren't so comfortable with hash tables and the reason I asked you to add some explanation was that only code doesn't look that good an SO answer where providing (only) code is discouraged :) Never mind, cheers :)!

Comment: The other point is, that the OP is most probably homework, and that [s]he should do some reading, too. (maybe I'll add some useless comments after a week or so ;-) **What** should I explain? fgets()? pointer dereferencing? The address-of operator? Structs? Linked lists ? arrays ? if...else ... ?

Comment: @wildplasser : Thanks for this great answer, and taking time to write the whole code :), That's works perfectly on my case (i was thinking as i said to pmg to a simple solution, that's not the simplest one, but it do greatly the job and with elegance).

Comment: But wat I do want to know: is it *really* that hard to read and understand? There are only three conditions and two loops in the whole program!

Comment: @wildplasser : No it's fine for me (i'm not familiar with hash tables), but the code is easy to read and to understand. Thanks again.

Comment: @wildplasser Who taught you how to indent code?  I need to punch that person in the face.

Comment: @Zack: learn how to ignore whitespace. It might improve your reading ability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the *simplest* solution, but...

If every entry looks like this:

```
0123456789;CUST098WZAX;35
```

... and the final two characters are always a value from `00` - `99`, you could use this value to index a bucket. This bucket is one item of an array of 100 (ie. 0-99, like the values), each of which points to a linked list of structures that store the strings belonging to that bucket.

With the strings sorted into buckets, the number of full-string comparisions required to identify duplicates is (hopefully) greatly reduced - just compare strings that are in the same bucket.

If all entries have the same value, this would put all entries in the same bucket, degrading this method to O(n^2) for the comparison step alone. But assuming a varied distribution of values this method will be faster in practice.

*(I have, of course, just described a hash table, but with a more naive hash function than would normally be used.)*

Answer (score 0):

The simplest algorithm:

1. Load original file in the memory as the array A of lines.
2. Create a separate array B of the same size.
3. Iterate over A. Do the linear search for the current line in B. If it is not in there, add it into B and into the output file.

This is very simple, brutal, inefficient O(n^2) solution. Very straightforward to implement, assuming you have basic C skills.

By the way, if the order does not matter, you may sort the file and then the task is even more straightforward. You just first sort the file, and then have the variable for the last line, against which you may check the current, and skip the current if it equals to the last one.