# Read a file but avoid duplicate data

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, duplicate-data

My code below reads a file in c which contains a list of students names(name and last name) and their scores, it prints the file, finds the average score, the highest score  and prints the students' names who obtained the highest score. My problem is that some student's names and grades are repeated in the file. So I want to know how could I read the same file but only print a list in which there are not duplicates names and scores. So next I can update the rest of information that I am looking for(ie. average).

```
 #define MAX 30 // Maximum number of students
 #define MINRANGE 0 // range of scores
 #define MAXRANGE 100
 int computeMax(double stSco[], int numSt); //Gets the average and highest score  
 void outputBest(double number[], char nameHigh[][16], int highPl, int totalSt);
                                         //Students with the highest score
 int main()
 {
    double score[MAX];
    char name[MAX][16];
    char fileName[80];
    int k, count=0, hgCt;
    stream dataFile;
    banner();
    printf("Type the name of file you want to read\n");
    scanf("%79[^\n]", fileName);
    puts(" Grade Student\n");//Header
    dataFile = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(dataFile == NULL){
    fatal( "Cannot open %s for reading", fileName);
}
    for(k=0; k < MAX; k++){
    fscanf(dataFile, "%lg %16[^\n]", &score[k], name[k]);
    if(feof(dataFile)) break;
    if(score[k] >= MINRANGE && score[k] <= MAXRANGE){ //Score validation
        printf("%6.1f %s\n", score[k], name[k]);
        count++; //It counts how many students there are actually
    }
    else{
        fatal( "There are illegal grades in file %s", fileName);
    }   
}
fclose(dataFile);
if(count == 0){ //Checks if file is empty
   fatal( "The file %s is empty", fileName);
}
else {
    hgCt = computeMax(score, count); //Stores the returned highest score
    outputBest(score, name, hgCt, count);
    bye();
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Create index table and sort using `qsort()`.  Walk through, skipping repeats.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200354/removing-all-duplicate-lines-from-a-file-using-c

Please see the above link.